Why is the select options showing up behind my div?
CSUI (content script) showing select options behind div
The select options shows up behind the card that select field. The styles are working fine but any time I open like a dropdown thats supposed to overlay on top of a div, it shows up behind the div instead. Has anyone solved this before?
content.tsx
import cssText from "data-text:~style.css"

import "~style.css"

export const getStyle = () => {
  const style = document.createElement("style")
  style.textContent = cssText.replaceAll(":root", ":host")
  return style
}

I've tried to change the z-index of the Select. This didn't work unfortunately.
<Label htmlFor="framework">Framework</Label>
<Select>
  <SelectTrigger id="framework">
    <SelectValue placeholder="Select" />
  </SelectTrigger>
  <SelectContent position="popper" style={{ zIndex: 1000 }}>
    <SelectItem value="next">Next.js</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem value="sveltekit">SvelteKit</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem value="astro">Astro</SelectItem>
    <SelectItem value="nuxt">Nuxt.js</SelectItem>
  </SelectContent>
</Select>


It turns out Plasmo set their shadow container's z-index to a really high number (2147483647 - Mersenne prime number) so i set my select component's z-index to +1 of that number.

So its fully fixed?
